# Excel 2016 - Removing 0's from array formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to have a formula to count the distinct number of elements in a column. However, the total number of entries in this column can vary.

Using the below formula, I can get this count iff the number of rows is exactly equal to X

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Data!C2:CX,Data!C2:CX))
```

If there are any blanks in this column, the value for that entry in the array is returned as 0. Because of this, this formula will return a #DIV/0! error. What I am hoping for is a way to remove those 0's because I do not care about blanks but only those cells which have data.

Is there a way I can either 1. Have X be variable so that it is always at the bottom or 2. remove the 0s from the formula so that I only return the count as expected?

Comment: Are your values numbers or text?

Comment: @ScottCraner values are text. Names specifically. Wanting to get a count of distinct string values in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to find the last row with values in them:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Data!C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C)),Data!C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz",C:C))))
```

This will now find the last cell with text in them and set that as the last cell in the range.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I'll accept as soon as it opens up.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `#DIV/0!` errors created by **interim** blank cells, append the second COUNTIF parameter with a zero-length string.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Data!C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("zzz", C:C)), Data!C2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH("zzz", C:C))&""))
```

Adjusted per [Scott Craner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) method of finding the last cell.